# Show $z\to\frac{2}{1-z}$ sends unit semicircle to $x=1$ and line $x=1$ to $x=0$

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis

How can we show that $z\to\frac{2}{1-z}$ sends the unit semicircle to $x=1$ and the line $x=1$ to $x=0$? $x=1$ implies $z=1+iy$.

Then the transformation sends it to i*(2/y).

Comment: *What* semicircle?

Comment: unit semicircle, i.e the unit circle except its in the upper  halfplane

Comment: Then we have $x=\Re(2i/y)=0$, which answers the second part of the question.

Comment: Thanks, ill check that out

Comment: Any circle has infinite semicircles, @maria. Apparently you mean the *upper* semicircle $\,h:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z|=1\,\,\wedge\,\,\operatorname{Im}(z)\ge 0\}\,$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know that any Möbius transformation (i.e. any map of the form $(az+b)/(cz+d)$) sends a circle or a line to another circle or line and that three points determine a circle or a line (definitely a line if $\inf$ is one of the points, then it's just a matter of checking a few points.  The upper half of the unit circle definitely maps to a line, since $1$ maps to $\inf$.  Also, $-1$ maps to 1 and $i$ maps to $1+i$, so the line $\Re(z)=1$ is the only choice.